# How do I solve the Dirac equation in Japanese?

Tags: keigo, academic-japanese

In a famous book of Richard Feynman there is a story about him struggling with the Japanese language when it comes to keigo.

Take a look at the excerpt from “Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!“, part 5:

> I was learning Japanese mainly for technical things, so I decided to check if this same problem existed among the scientists.
> At the institute the next day, I said to the guys in the office, “How would I say in Japanese, ‘I solve the Dirac Equation’?”
> They said such­-and­-so.
> “OK. Now I want to say, ‘Would you solve the Dirac Equation?’ — how do I say that?“ 
> “Well, you have to use a different word for ‘solve,’” they say.
> “Why?” I protested. “When *I* solve it, I do the same damn thing as when you solve it!”
> “Well, yes, but it’s a different word­­ it’s more polite.”
> I gave up. I decided that wasn’t the language for me, and stopped learning Japanese.

What would be those Japanese phrases like? Is there a keigo version even for a verb like “solve” that has a rather abstract meaning to me?

Comment: Surely the difference would only be 解きました vs 解いていただけますか

Comment: I'd forgotten about this story.  Such arrogance on the part of Feynman!  Sigh.  That said, we are not a translation  site.  On the one hand, it would be hard to guess what exactly Feynman was told; on the other hand, what has your research led you to understand about how to say "solve" in Japanese.

Comment: @A.Ellett: From the context of the story I'd have concluded that the words Feynman is talking about are *different*, like the 言う/申す pair. I've never seen such a keigo pair for 解く. By the way, I'm not asking for translation or anything beyond a reasonable guess.

Comment: 「解く」の尊敬語・・・ (。´･ω･)?

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird story. He changed the grammar from one sentence to the next, so it's not outrageous to think the Japanese sentence would change too. But yeah, I don't think such a pair exists for solve. Maybe he knew pairs like that exist and created a scenario after the fact to express his surprise at it.

Comment: https://lucylou.tumblr.com/post/966986488/richard-feynman-on-learning-japanese/amp `Would you like to glance at my lousy garden?` `May I observe your gorgeous garden?` `May I hang my eyes on your most exquisite gardens?` 「ご覧になる」「拝見する」ですかね？3つ目は何でしょう、「拝観する」とか？ これホントの話なんですかね～？？ (o￢ω￢o)

Comment: He could’ve hired a better teacher…

Comment: @firegurafiku That's quite a fair couple of points you bring up.

Comment: @Chocolate  Again I think Feynman is perhaps not remembering things correctly.  The only phrase I can think of for #3 would be 目にかかる, only because I suppose could be too literally-mindedly **mistranslated** as to *hang one's eyes*.  Could it be the verb being looked for by Feynman wasn't "seeing" so much as "visiting/meeting" someone in their garden?

Comment: @A.Ellett Maybe お目にかける

Comment: @Ellett そうですね・・「お目にかかる」は「会う」の謙譲語ですし、「お目にかける」は「見せる」の謙譲語ですよね・・ Feynmanさんは、記憶違いか何かしているような気がしますね・・

Comment: Another thought:  if you don't recognize the relation between とく and といて, it could be that Feynman heard 解きました and 解いていただけますか as far more different than a native speaker (or someone reasonably conversant in Japanese) ever would.  Hardly any speaker of English notices the difference between "I go" vs "I went" (at least in terms of "go"->"went" as completely changing the root word).  This difference between とく and といて is much less dramatic (after all the root word hasn't even been changed), but it could have led to a perception of a bigger difference than there actually is.

Comment: I think these comments should be put together as an answer.  They've been quite instructive for myself.  I don't think I should be the one to do it though.  My comfort and confidence with keigo and the like is very shaky.  But someone who has a firmer grasp of keigo (such as a native speaker) could certainly tie these different threads together.  (Or would someone be willing to help me clean up my own misconceptions when it comes to keigo?)

Comment: Just FYI, I checked the translated version of the book...and found out unfortunately the English sentences ("I solve.." and "Would you...") are used untranslated.

Comment: I'm going to be pondering this one, because I have definitely heard multiple words for solving problems, but none that jump out as being different for 1st/2nd person yet. However, a related point is that the opposite often occurs. 聞きました can be used to say that I asked someone, heard back from them, or got an answer, which are all different. Of course, these can all be clarified using different terms, but it remains that some terms can fit what another language finds different meanings.